# Find the numpy 2d array use customized index in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering what is the most convenient way for finding the numpy array value with customized coordinates.

For example, I create a numpy array like

```
[[1,2,3,4]
 [5,6,7,8]]
```

The x coordinate is`[1, 3, 5, 7]`, and the y coordinate is `[1,1.5]`.

I hope to get the value '8' by using the coordinate `(7,1.5)` rather than using numpy index `(3,1)`.

What is the most elegant way to do that?

Comment: you can look into the package xarray for labeled data arrays http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

Comment: I don't see the connection between the 2d array and those `coordinates`.  `numpy ` (not 'bumpy') does not implement 'coordinates'.

Comment: you want to force 5 labels on a row of size 4?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the misunderstanding about the 'bumpy' and 'numpy'. I understand numpy itself cannot make it. I am just wondering is there any more elegant way to make it happen.